# Change color of Text inside List view in android

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have to change color of multiple selected items (Text views) in List view. What I am doing here is, when user selects items from list views, color should be change to BLUE and when user deselects items, color should change to by default color (here Black). I have been through few tutorials and implemented one little demo. But I am not getting, how to deal with color change. Below is my code...

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

## listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public View row;
    ListView lview;
    ListViewAdapter lviewAdapter;

    private final static String month[] = {"January","February","March","April","May",
        "June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, month);

        lview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);

        lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }




}
```

### ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<Boolean> saved = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    Activity context;
    String title[];
    String description[];

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewTitle;

    }




    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);


    return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Give @Anchit's answer a try. It should work fine. There is another way which does not involve selectors. But it isn't as straight-forward as some of the answers here.

Comment: ok...great..I am on it...will let u know...

Comment: @Vikram...I'm facing the same problem with Anchit's answer also...  random color changes all over the place...

Comment: The solution i have provided works fine for me... and i usually do this.

Comment: ya but color is also changing of not selected items also...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

please refer this for choosing the appropriate states for selector

Comment: Are none of the answers posted below working for you? Would you like me to post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                 TextView textView1 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   if(lv.isItemChecked(arg2))
                         textView1.setTextColor(your selected state color);
                   else
                       textView1.setTextColor(your unselected state color);

            }
        });
```

Comment: @AnilBhatiya This is not a good solution. `ListView` recycles views. And if your list of items is long enough to scroll, you will see random color changes all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the selector.xml inside res/drawable like i have created the one below.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#cc003300"/>
    <item android:color="#cc003300"></item>

</selector>
```

then assign it to the textview in xml.

```
 android:textColor="@drawable/selector_btn_textcolor_green"
```

update your code as

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_btn_textcolor_green"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: i tried above but it is not working. only default color is working, when i press no effect in this.

Comment: It is working absolutely fine for me. What is the problem that you are facing

Comment: i set the default color as black and when focused i set red. but on focus also black color is only shown

Comment: Please check your Selector or post your XML

Comment: <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/view" 
             android:focusable="true" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         
            <TextView 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18.0dip"
                android:textColor="@color/selector"
                /> here for selector i gave above coding. pls check and help me

Comment: Where have you defined your selector.xml

Just do in same manner as the above code is provided

Comment: i added my selector file in res/color folder and the selector file codings are same as above

Answer (score 0):

for the listitem, you can keep the drawable as an xml resource which you can keep in drawable folder. In that you can handle pressed, focused, normal condition explicitly to different colors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get the selected position of your Item , so you can do this by passing the selected Item to your adapter in your List onItemClickListener : 
in your adapter class add :

```
public void setSelectedPosition(int pos)
{
    selectedPos = pos;
}
```

in your Activity you call this function of your adapter :

```
public void selectPosition(int position) {
    ((YourCustomAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).setSelectedPosition(position);
}
```

and in your ListItemClick Listener of your List :

```
YourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        {
             selectPosition(position);

        }
    });
```

here selectedPos is a global variable which take your Selected Item , so you have the selected Item in your Adapter, then you can use this in getView() function :

```
if(selectedPos == position)
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_red);       
}
else
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_light_grey);
}
```

Comment: User can select multiple items.

Comment: hey Arsh I am not getting your answer..would u pls explain me in detail?

Comment: @Anil : as vikram mentioned,this answer works for single selection if you want to multiple selection you have to pass an array of selected position to your adapter and check them on getView function.setting color in listener won't work on ListView because of ListView Recycling behavior.tell me which part you can't understand

Comment: actually where I have to put this function setSelectedPosition(int pos)? In Adapter class? and where I have to put this if/else condition?

Comment: Look at the edited Answer,yes setSelectedPosition(int pos) will be on your adapter and you check if/else statement on adapter class,getView function,Hence for multiple selection you should change these and add each selection to an array of positions then pass it to your adapter

Comment: hey, I am not getting where i have to put public void selectPosition(int position) {
    ((YourCustomAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).setSelectedPosition(position);
}.

Comment: I put it in my MainActivity, but getting error that Create getListView() method..

Comment: this code should be in activity which contains and setup your List,getListView() works on ListActivity and not Activity so if you have Activity then define your adapter global then replace my code as : youradapter.setSelectedPosition(position).

Comment: hey Arash, I implemented, but when I click on items in list view, color is not changing...

Comment: you have to debug it,it's working for my apps,you probabely missed something.check your getView and place breakpoints on if statement to find that your position which passed is ok.

Comment: hey Arash, I've been trying to implement it, but not through it yet. Coludn't change the color of seleted row in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Create new layout xml file and copy the entire code from simple_list_item_1.xml in external libraries, then change according to you.

custom_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#1ca099"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
 />
```

Then in the activity.java file:

```
 ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_text,cultural);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```